# Complex SQL query aggregation and grouping on athena

Tags: sql, string, count, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table like this:

```
|     db      |      chat_id      |   Admin    |     user      |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+---------------+
|    db_1     |      chat_id1     |    max     |     greg      |
|    db_1     |      chat_id2     |    max     |     bob       |
|    db_1     |      chat_id3     |    max     |     greg      |
|    db_1     |      chat_id2     |    helen   |     greg      |
|    db_2     |      chat_id1     |    alan    |     greg      |
```

I would like to retrieve the **number of chat** performed **by users** for each **database (db)** and the last part where I fail, retrieve also **a list of all mentors by users**.

The final output should be like this for example (notice there is only one time max for greg in the admin column)

```
|     db      |      user     |  nb_of_chat  |     admins    |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|    db_1     |      greg     |      3       |   max, helen  |
|    db_1     |      bob      |      1       |      max      |
|    db_2     |      greg     |      1       |      alan     |
```

I wrote the following query but it doesn't aggregate the admins and i have separated nb_of chats/mentors.

```
SELECT db, user, COUNT(chat_id), admins
FROM "chat_db"."chats" 
GROUP BY db, user, admins;
```

As expected I am getting the following result (but I only want it on one line by db/user with grouped admin in the same column):

```
|     db      |      user     |  nb_of_chat  |     admins    |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|    db_1     |      greg     |      2       |       max     |
|    db_1     |      greg     |      1       |      helen    |
|    ...      |      ...      |     ...      |      ...      |
```

Have you an idea how to perform it ?

Thank you for your time !

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firsly, remove `admins`from the `group by` clause, since you want to aggregate it. Then, in Presto, you can do string aggregation as follows:

```
select db,user, count(*) no_of_chats, 
    array_join(array_agg(admins), ', ') all_admins
from  "chat_db"."chats" 
group by db, user;
```

You can add an `order by` clause to `array_agg()` if needed:

```
select db,user, count(*) no_of_chats, 
    array_join(array_agg(admins order by admins), ', ') all_admins
from  "chat_db"."chats" 
group by db, user;
```

Note that I changed `count(chat_id)` to `count(*)`: both are equivalent (since `chat_id` probably is a non-`null`able column), and the former is (sligthly) more efficient, and makes the intent clearer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_agg()`:

```
select db, user, count(chat_id), array_agg(admins)
from  "chat_db"."chats" 
group by db, user;
```

If you want one row per `db`:

```
select db, count(*) as num_chats, count(distinct user) as num_users, array_agg(admins)
from  "chat_db"."chats" 
group by db;
```